# Alternative queries equivalent to Oracle's Analyze Table Query

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle

Are there queries in other databases equivalent to Oracle's very useful `ANALYZE TABLE..` ? I am looking for alternatives for the following Database vendors:

1. MySQL
2. MS SQL Server [2000, 2005, 2008]

Thanks in advance

Comment: In Oracle, you should be using DBMS_STATS not ANALYZE. ANALYZE is deprecated

Answer (score 2):

MySQL has `ANALYZE TABLE` as well, see here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/analyze-table.html

Comment: Great post. Learnt something new today! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at SQLServer-DBA.com at [this page](http://www.sqlserver-dba.com/2011/05/sql-server-query-optimizer-and-statistics-.html) for a statistics overview and [another page](http://www.sqlserver-dba.com/statistics/) on how to gather statistics in MS SQL Server. I don't know of other vendor implementations.

Further research shows that SQL Server has the [CREATE STATISTICS](http://ss64.com/sql/stats_c.html) command, which looks to be the equivalent.